# could not autowire / could not create bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dependencies

I am getting quite a few errors that occur when trying to access my app through a browser. errors are:

> Could not autowire method: public void
> com.ProjectOne.Util.CustomHibernateDaoSupport.anyMethodName(org.hibernate.SessionFactory);
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for
> dependency: expected at least 1
>
> Could not autowire method: public void
> com.ProjectOne.Util.CustomHibernateDaoSupport.anyMethodName(org.hibernate.SessionFactory);
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for
> dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Account model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

accountService

```
package com.ProjectOne.Account.Service;

import com.ProjectOne.Account.Model.Account;

public interface accountService {

    public Account retrieveAccount(Long id);
}
```

accountServiceImpl

```
@Service("accountService")
public class accountServiceImpl implements accountService {

    @Autowired
    private accountDAO accountDAO;
    
    @Override
    public Account retrieveAccount(Long id) {
        return accountDAO.retrieveAccount(id);
    }
}
```

accountDAO

```
package com.ProjectOne.Account.DAO;

import com.ProjectOne.Account.Model.Account;


public interface accountDAO {

    public Account retrieveAccount(Long id);
}
```

accountDAOImpl

```
@Repository("accountDAO")
public class accountDAOImpl extends CustomHibernateDaoSupport implements accountDAO {

    public Account retrieveAccount(Long id) {
        
        return null;
    }

}
```

CustomDaoHibernateSupport

```
public abstract class CustomHibernateDaoSupport extends HibernateDaoSupport
{    
    @Autowired
    public void anyMethodName(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

DataSource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
 
<bean 
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>properties/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
 
<bean id="dataSource" 
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
 
</beans>
```

hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
 
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
 
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
 
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
 
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>com.ProjectOne.Account.Account</value>
    </list>
    </property>
 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

stacktrace:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
27 Apr 2015 13:59:04 ERROR DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.ProjectOne.Util.CustomHibernateDaoSupport.anyMethodName(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.ProjectOne.Util.CustomHibernateDaoSupport.anyMethodName(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:606)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: Post complete stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: See `private accountDAO accountDAO;` line in `accountServiceImpl` class, the name of object instance is same as name of the interface. Why is this so ? *Why don't u follow Java naming convention to avoid confusion ?*

Comment: Check [Spring + Hibernate example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-annotation-mysql-example/) to get more clear idea on how to use `HibernateDaoSupport` class. Modify ur code & follow coding standards while writing code bcoz, it's very difficult to understand such ugly code.

Comment: Updated question with the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you are trying to autowire a reference, in your case `SessionFactory`, to multiple beans which are of same type. So try change the method as follows:

```
@Autowired
public void anyMethodName(@Qualifier("sessionFactory")SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
```

Comment: The error says `No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1` so spring is not able to find a bean of type `SessionFactory`, even after using Qualifier, I think Spring cannot inject the dependency.

Comment: @Shaun, update the question with complete stacktrace of the exception to understand the issue better.

Comment: @Shaun dude, I only edited the answer, I didn't look deep into your question.